# Treat inputs in React without forms

Tags: reactjs

For classic input fields in forms (e.g. registration), formik or react hook from are definitely a great thing. But how would you approach a web app with many different input fields. Let's take a look at Google Docs. There are also a lot of input fields that change a state, but you don't pack that in Forms, do you? Would you develop something like that from scratch or is there an effective framework in React which carries out the validations and calls the Redux reducer more or less automatically?

Comment: There's many rich text editor tools out there that can provide bits of that functionality, and are customizable. But you'll most likely have to modify and integrate them together for your specific needs... Please consider creating a [minimal workable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as this site isn't meant for opinion-related questions such as this.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm not interested in the text editor, that was just an example. My question aims at a scenario in which many input fields influence the application as a whole. My dumbest approach would be to give everyone an onChange handler and another approach would be a form that encompasses the entire application. Maybe the right way is somewhere in the middle. I just see a form framework as wrong and wanted to get to know other solutions.